# Iptables Restricting Access By Time

Tags: iptables

How to control internet time access for each IP?

How to add time to this rule: `iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.56 -j ACCEPT`?

I tried this

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.56 -m time --timestart 13:00 --timestop 14:00 -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.56 --match time --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri --timestart 09:00 --timestop 10:00 -j ACCEPT
```

but it doesn't work

Maybe there is another way to do it?

```
Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

root@router:/home/wlodek# iptables -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.56         anywhere             TIME from 09:00:00 to 10:00:00 on Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri UTC
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

IP: 192.168.0.56 - **has a connection**  `iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.56 -j ACCEPT`

IP: 192.168.0.56 - **no connection**  `iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.56 -j ACCEPT` **+ time**

Comment: What exactly does not work? Can you see your rule when listing the chain `iptables -L FORWARD`?

Comment: @Jonas -> When I add time to rule 'iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.71 -j ACCEPT' -> at all, no internet connection.

Comment: I assume you're doing this on a routing device. As you wrote the rule `192.168.0.56` to only allow traffic between 9 and 10 it seems reasonable that the traffic outside this window will be blocked. Run `date -u` on your router to make sure your trying to connect inside the right time-frame.

Comment: @Jonas  date and date -u show different dates:)!

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Jonas Thank you very much !!:):)!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`iptables` is working with UTC time not your local time.

Try the following formula:

> ```
> iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.0.56 --match time --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri --timestart $(date -u -d @$(date "+%s" -d "09:00") +%H:%M) --timestop $(date -u -d @$(date "+%s" -d "10:00") +%H:%M) -j ACCEPT
> ```

This converts your local start and end time to UTC before handing it over to `iptables`.

Of course you can replace start time `09:00` and end time `10:00` by any other time.

Comment: Does this also work on Monday morning/Friday afternoon? Because if it is still Sunday according to UTC/already Saturday will it even get to the converted times or will it be blocked by the filter on the weekday?

Comment: @Graipher I expect the `--weekdays` flag to be in UTC, too. Therefor the converted time will always be considered to be on the specified `--weekdays`. Depending on your time zone and time difference to UTC it might make sense to adjust `--weekdays`. e.g. if you want to enable a rule Mondays between 2am and 3am and you're 4 hours ahead of UTC the converted time will be 22pm on Sunday. Therefore it would be wise to set `--weekdays` to `Sun` instead of `Mon` even when its enabled on Monday at 2am in your local time zone. Otherwise you would have an offset of 24h minus your time difference to UTC.

Comment: doen't work on ubuntu 20.04